# Keras question about training with frozen layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm going through [this](https://www.wouterbulten.nl/blog/tech/getting-started-with-generative-adversarial-networks/) GAN tutorial, and the author sets up a `discriminator` like this:

```
model_discriminator = Sequential()
model_discriminator.add(net_discriminator)
```

where `net_discriminator` is another `Sequential` model.

He then sets up the `adversarial` model like this:

```
model_adversarial = Sequential()
model_adversarial.add(net_generator)

# Disable layers in discriminator
for layer in net_discriminator.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model_adversarial.add(net_discriminator)
```

where `net_generator` is another `sequential` model.

Both models are trained at the same time using `train_on_batch`.

What I don't understand is how the weights of the `net_discriminator` part of `model_adversarial` get updated by training `model_discriminator`. To me, they're two separate networks and training one model which contains the layers of `net_discriminator` should not effect the other. Also, the layers are frozen in the `adversarial` model so isn't that supposed to stop them from being trained?

Can someone provide me a lower level explanation of how this works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question is already been given by the author of the tutorial in the following lines where he says:

- It is important to note that we add the discriminator network to a
  new Sequential model and do not directly compile the discriminator
  itself. We do this because the discriminator is also required in the
  next step and we are able to do so by adding it to a new model before
  compiling.
- Our adversarial model uses random noise as its input, and outputs the 
  eventual prediction of the discriminator on the generated images. This why we 
  added the discriminator to a new model in the previous step, by doing so we 
  are able to reuse the network here.

So, I think the way he is creating `model_discriminator` model by adding `net_discriminator` model to a `new Sequential()` layer is the reason how the weights of the `net_discriminator` part of `model_adversarial` get updated by training `model_discriminator`, as during the training of `model_discriminator`, it's actually `net_discriminator` part of it which is getting trained.

Answer to second question:

According to the author,

> If we would use normal back propagation here on the full adversarial
>   model we would slowly push the discriminator to update itself and
>   start classifying fake images as real. Namely, the target vector of
>   the adversarial model consists of all ones. To prevent this we must
>   freeze the part of the model that belongs to the discriminator.

So, the above expaination by the author clearly suggests why we want to freeze layers of discriminator part of the adverserial model. The `adverserial` model contains both `generator` and `discriminator` networks. The `adverserial` model uses random noise as its input and outputs the eventual prediction of the `discriminator` on the generated images. So, here the already trained `discriminator` network is used just for prediction, no need to involve it in training.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I was wondering more about the lower level of how this works. My first thought was that adding the discriminator network to the discriminator model would add a copy of it with it's own separate weights. I understand that this is not correct but I can't find anything in the keras documentation where it states that adding a sequential model to multiple sequential models allows the weights to be shared and updated dynamically for all models.